# How do I reference a page within a DocuSign template?

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I'm creating a document template, and within that template there's a paragraph that makes a reference to a table in a previous page. Because the table might not always appear in the same page, I don't want to hardcode the page number.

Is there a way to tag a paragraph and then have DocuSign generate the page number, much like it's done with Latex for example?

### Added

My team is using FTL (Apache templates, basically HTML + variables) for creating templates, filling them out, and then sending an envelope.

Within the templates we have DocuSign tags such as <ds-signature ...> and I was wondering if there was a tag to mark a place so I could reference it somewhere else.

For example, I could have a table in page 1 labeled @peopleTable (made-up syntax), and I could use @peopleTable in other pages, e.g., "See table in page @peopleTable" which would render as "See table in page 1"

Comment: Do you mean envelope template? And are you using eSignature, CLM, or another DocuSign product. Is your question about placing a DocuSign field (tag) in the right place on your documents? Please update your question with more information, I don't understand your situation at this point

Comment: My team is using FTL (Apache templates, basically HTML + variables) for creating templates, filling them out, and then sending an envelope. Within the templates we've DocuSign tags such as `<ds-signature ...>` and I was wondering if there was a tag to mark a place so I could reference it somewhere else. For example, I could've a table in page 1 labeled `@peopleTable` (made-up syntax), and I could use `@peopleTable` in other pages, e.g., "See table in page @peopleTable" which would render as "See table in page 1"

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want to set a page number you can use our Anchor Text (Auto Placement) feature, the system will search for the hidden (words written in white font) text regardless of which page is in.

https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=gbo1643332197980&topicId=dwz1578456404912.html&_LANG=enus

We hope this information helps

Regards
Adrian
DocuSign Developer Support

Answer (score 0):

> [in the html document we create from] templates we have DocuSign tags such as <ds-signature ...> and I was wondering if there was a tag to mark a place so I could reference it somewhere else.

With DocuSign anchor text positioning, you can create reference place(s) in your documents for the placement of DocuSign tag(s). See Adrian's answer.

> there's a paragraph that makes a reference to a table in a previous page. Because the table might not always appear in the same page, I don't want to hardcode the page number.

But unfortunately we don't have a way to translate a reference to a page number of a document and then display that page number to the signer.

### Suggestions

- From your question, maybe just say "see the prior page"?
- If the table is a set of signatures, then some folks create a "signature page" as the last page of the document set. That way you can refer to the table via "see the last page."